# How to calculate the "center" point

Tags: algorithm

I have such points

```
pts = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEP05.png"],"Byte"]]]];
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

If I use the normal method to calculate the center point, it will be in the red area.

```
ListPlot[pts, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[Mean[pts]]}]
```

[image]

Now I want to calculate the specific "center" point. When the point in the **denser area**, it has greater weight. I think the "center" point I'm after should be at the bottom of that red point. But how to calculate it?

Answer (score 11):

The median is known to be more robust against outliers than the mean:

```
ListPlot[pts, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[Mean[pts]], Green, 
   Point[SpatialMedian[pts]]}]
```

[image]

have also a look on the other "Location Statistics" [in this guide on descriptive statistics](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DescriptiveStatistics.html).

Comment: Note that `SpatialMedian` requires you to load the `MultivariateStatistics` package in versions of Mathematica before 11.1.  Also note that the `SpatialMedian` does not calculate the "median" as the term is usually used.  (I agree it's probably the simplest thing to get at what the OP is asking for, though.)

Comment: `Median` also work but it takes the median componentwise. This is however not rotationindependent. (But if the different axes have different scaling, this might not be a problem at all...)

Comment: +1 It should be mentioned that there are many many different types of medians for multivariate data because the univariate median doesn't generalize to higher dimensions. I only see "Median" and "SpatialMedian" implemented in MMA but there are others such as Oja's Simplex Median, Beach and the Halfspace Median, Simplical Depth Median, and Convex Hull Stripping Median. Each one has its own advantages, disadvantages, robustness, computational complexity, etc.

Answer (score 7):

One possible way to operationalize the requirement *"When the point in the denser area, it has greater weight"* is to weight each point by the number of neighbors within a specified distance:

```
nf = Nearest[pts];
radius = 50;
weightedData = WeightedData[pts, Length[nf[#, {All, radius}]] & /@ pts];
center = Mean[weightedData];
ListPlot[pts, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[Mean[pts]], Green, Point @ center}]
```

[image]

With `radius = 100` we get

[image]